# Silent printing for mobile devices via Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, printing, silent

I'm currently using Scalefusion for kiosk mode but it's not working the way I want, I'm still seeing the print preview. I tried some JS code but couldn't make it. I want the pdf link I created to be printed without print preview or download. Has anyone been able to achieve this or have any suggestions?

Edit(More Info):

When the user clicks the Show Receipt button on the website opened on their mobile device, a pop-up window will appear and silent printing will take place. When the popup is shown, I want the pdf link I created to be printed or downloaded without a print preview. I'm currently trying to do this with javascript using scalefusion. I'm sorry I can't give you more information since I don't have any other information.

Kind regards

Comment: Android's printing framework does not support silent printing. I would be rather surprised if Chrome did.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @CommonsWare . I will let you know if i find something.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I've tried pspdfkit before, as far as I can see, skia and foxit are the same kind of thing. Actually I can create pdf and upload this pdf to aws. What I can't do is print it without showing print preview on mobile devices. At this point, I am open to using everything, including writing the 3rd party application myself if necessary. There are restaurants that can do this with a tablet. I honestly wonder how they can do it.  @KJ

Comment: @KJ I used scalefusion to test mobile kiosk mode. I can use anything to achieve this right now. Is there any 3rd party android app or any external api that you know can do silent printing?

Comment: Honestly, I have no experience with mobile printing, it's new for me. What's your suggestion? @KJ

Comment: So I need to send it to the printer in a non-vector format. I was trying to convert the reciepts in black and white with a certain design to pdf and print it like that. Well, in cases where there are multiple users and therefore multiple printers, a general solution is needed to do this because it can be of different brands and I want to print out with the design shown on the website. So I'm looking for a 3rd party or an api or a different solution. I'm using qz for desktop but couldn't find anything for mobile. @KJ

Comment: Epson doesn't support bluetooth connections as far as I can see